# Passing JSF URL parameters to CDI Bean

Tags: jsf-2.2, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I am in the process of redesigning a project and I've come across what I think is a bug but Im confused as to where the bug is originating from.

Basically all I am trying to do is pass a URL parameter to the backing bean. Nothing magic and there are loads of different ways of achieving this. The following are the ones I use regularly;

1. I can change the bean from @Named to @ManagedBean and then use the @ManagedProperty
2. I can access the param using `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()` and then get the desired param from the Map
3. Or I can use: `<f:metadata><f:viewParam name="id" value="#{backingBean.id}"/></f:metadata>`

When I'm using JSF 2.1 with Glassfish 3+ all three of these work perfectly. The problem is that my current project is using JSF 2.2 and Glassfish 4 and none of these work! No matter what I do the parameter is never set and always just ends up as null.

I'm not sure how to track this down further. The obvious changes from the last project are that I am using Glassfish 4 instead of 3, JavaEE 7 instead of 6, and JSF 2.2 instead of 2.1.
I don't get any errors or exceptions that I can post.

Is there anything else I can test or any alternative solutions I can try. Failing that is anybody aware of any reported bugs or changes that might cause this. Lastly can anybody reproduce this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem relates to the namespace!

If you declare the **old** namespace everything **will work fine**;

```
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
```

If you declare the **new** namespace it **won't** work;

```
xmlns://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core
```

Be careful as netbeans will automatically populate your namespaces. I really hope this saves somebody some time!